# java spring call rest webservice error 404

Tags: java, spring, rest

hi I´m getting a error 404 when I call a rest webservice

The web service method is :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/natlist", produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<Nacionalidades>> getnatlist() 
{
     List<Nacionalidades> nacionalidadesList = new ArrayList<>();
        .....
     return new ResponseEntity<>(nacionalidadesList, HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

the call to the web service

```
 ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(HttpClients.createDefault());
     RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
     try
     {
        ResponseEntity<Nacionalidades[]> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, Nacionalidades[].class);
        HttpStatus statusCode = responseEntity.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == HttpStatus.OK)
        {
            Nacionalidades[] natArr = responseEntity.getBody();
            ....        
        }
    }
```

The web service method is :

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Can you post whole class with this method? Did you add @RestController annotation on the class level?

Comment: if you can enable debug logging for _org.springframework_ package it will say what is your problem

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you use path parameter instead of value? Did you try this?

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/natlist", produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: "value" is an alias for "path"